# Wrong encoding with Python BeautifulSoup + MySql

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, urllib2, beautifulsoup

I'm working with the BeautifulSoup python library.
I used the urllib2 library to download the HTML code from a page, and then I have parsed it with BeautifulSoup.
I want to save some of the HTML content into a MySql table, but I'm having some problems with the encoding. The MySql table is encoded with 'utf-8' charset.

Some examples:

When I download the HTML code and parse it with BeautifulSoup I have something like:

`"Ver las \xc3\xbaltimas noticias. Ent\xc3\xa9rate de las noticias de \xc3\xbaltima hora con la mejor cobertura con fotos y videos"`

The correct text would be:

`"Ver las últimas noticias. Entérate de las noticias de última hora con la mejor cobertura con fotos y videos"`

I have tried to encode and decode that text with multiple charsets, but when I insert it into MySql I have somethig like:

`"Ver las Ãºltimas noticias y todos los titulares de hoy en Yahoo! Noticias Argentina. EntÃ©rate de las noticias de Ãºltima hora con la mejor cobertura con fotos y videos"`

I'm having problems with the encoding, but I don't know how to solve them.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You have correct UTF-8 data coming out of BeautifulSoup, but it's being stored in a normal string type, not python's native unicode string type. I think this is what you need to do:

```
codecs.decode(your_string, 'utf-8')
```

And then the string should be the proper data type and encoding to send to mysql.

An example:

```
>>> codecs.decode("Ver las \xc3\xbaltimas noticias. Ent\xc3\xa9rate de las noticias de \xc3\xbaltima hora con la mejor cobertura con fotos y videos", 'utf-8')
u'Ver las \xfaltimas noticias. Ent\xe9rate de las noticias de \xfaltima hora con la mejor cobertura con fotos y videos'
>>> print _
Ver las últimas noticias. Entérate de las noticias de última hora con la mejor cobertura con fotos y videos
```

Comment: By the way, I consider encoding problems to be a form of cruel and unusual punishment, and I expect mondo upvotes for tracking this down. ;)

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup returns all data as unicode strings. First triple check that the unicode strings are ccorrect. If not then there is some issue with the encoding of the input data.